# Search & replace in MySql, using regex

Tags: mysql, regex

I have a row with content that can look like this:

```
bla bla bla [ATTACH]123456[/ATTACH] bla bla bla
bla bla bla [ATTACH]78912[/ATTACH] bla something bla
```

I need to search the row for all occurences of [ATTACH]number[/ATTACH] and replace it like this:

`[ATTACH]123456[/ATTACH]` should become `[sharedmedia=core:attachments:123456]`

or...

`[ATTACH]78912[/ATTACH]` should become `[sharedmedia=core:attachments:78912]`

Comment: Great. Looks like fun.

Comment: Thank you for providing a report on the status of your current efforts. Did you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

SQL is not optimized for this sort of work.  The following might accomplish what you want:

```
update table t
    set content = replace(replace(content, '[ATTACH]', '[sharedmedia=core:attachments:'
                                 ), '[/ATTACH]', ']'
                         )
    where content like '[ATTACH]%[/ATTACH]';
```

This assumes that all occurrence of `[ATTACH]` are followed by a number.

Comment: @Akyhne . . . That is why I always try to line up my parentheses, so I can visually see when I might be missing one.

Comment: Works this way:

    update table t
        set content = replace(replace(content, '[ATTACH]', '[sharedmedia=core:attachments:'
                                     ), '[/ATTACH]', ']'
                             )
        where content like '%[ATTACH]%[/ATTACH]%';

This assumes that all occurrence of `[ATTACH]` are followed by a number.