# MySQL Search/Replace with a variable number

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I have some string which I need to replace in my database using a SQL query. The string is:

> [attachment=**NUMBER**]image.jpg[/attacment]

I want to wrap that image.jpg with an HTML image tag, but the **NUMBER** is screwing me up because it will be different for each string. Is there a wildcard character I can use in this query which will find any number?

Here's my search/replace query:

```
UPDATE `hd_posts`
SET `post_content` = 
       replace(post_content, 
               '[attachment=NUMBER]', 
               '<img src="http://mydomain.com/my-theme/images/')
```

and then...

```
UPDATE `hd_posts`
 SET `post_content` = replace(post_content, '[/attachment]', '" />')
```

...so that I will end up with this:

```
<img src="http://mydomain.com/my-theme/images/image.jpg" />
```

Can anyone help? What do I use for **NUMBER**? I have a feeling that this is not too difficult, but I am a complete novice at this. Of course I've searched and searched, but I can't find this exact situation anywhere from which to learn. These two almost gave me what I need:

[MySQL REPLACE variable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15806609/mysql-replace-variable-string)
[Search & replace in MySql, using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22426115/search-replace-in-mysql-using-regex)

but not quite. I'm still confused! Thanks for any help.

If I use that first link as an example...

```
UPDATE `hd_posts` 
  SET `post_content` = 
         CONCAT(SUBSTRING(post_content, 1, 
                          INSTR(post_content,'[attachment') - 1),
                SUBSTRING(post_content, 
                          INSTR(post_content, ']'), 
                          LENGTH(post_content) 
                            - INSTR(post_content, '[attachment'))
                )
```

I have no idea...in that example he was trying to replace a string with '' (remove it), but I don't see how he is doing that, and I don't see how I can learn from it enough to do what I need to do.

Comment: You have a *right* answer at the first link for your requirement too.

Comment: So, should I do this:

   UPDATE hd_posts
       SET post_content = CONCAT(SUBSTRING(post_content, 1, 
                    INSTR(post_content,'[attachment') - 1),SUBSTRING(post_content , 
                    INSTR(post_content, ']'), 
                    LENGTH(post_content) - INSTR(post_content, '&add_id')))

I'm afraid to try, but would that work? It's a HUGE database so it will be a major hassle to restore from backup if I mess up.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work, because there are two closing brackets: ']'

Comment: @Ravinder I forgot to replace '&add_id' with '[attachment' in that comment above, but I would appreciate any help you could give me here.

Comment: What is the exact string format you have? Post it in the question. Not in the comments, please.

Comment: @Ravinder Sorry, I had it all wrong, but I added the code up in the question area using that first example as a guide...

Comment: @Ravinder I think I'm starting to understand the example (eureka). He's removing everything between '&add_id' -1 (to the left of it) and '&more'. He's taking the string before and joining it to the string after. Right? But that doesn't work for me. Each number is different and each image is different, so I can't do anything between 'this' and 'that'.

Comment: The second example doesn't work for me either, because he's keeping the number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `[attachment=NUMBER]image.jpg[/attacment]`.

There is a typo in `[/attacment]`. Letter `h` was missing.
Change it to         `[/attachment]`

If the format of content is always this, then

```
set @pc := '[attachment=NUMBER]image.jpg[/attachment]';
set @instr := INSTR(@pc, ']');
set @start_tag := substring(@pc, 1, @instr);
set @end_tag := '[/attachment]';
set @image_url := 
  replace(
    replace( @pc, @start_tag, 
             '<img src="http://mydomain.com/my-theme/images/'
    ), @end_tag, '" />');

select @pc;
+-------------------------------------------+
| @pc                                       |
+-------------------------------------------+
| [attachment=NUMBER]image.jpg[/attachment] |
+-------------------------------------------+

select @instr, @start_tag, @end_tag;
+--------+---------------------+---------------+
| @instr | @start_tag          | @end_tag      |
+--------+---------------------+---------------+
|     19 | [attachment=NUMBER] | [/attachment] |
+--------+---------------------+---------------+

select @image_url;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| @image_url                                                  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| <img src="http://mydomain.com/my-theme/images/image.jpg" /> |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Demo** @ [***SQL Fiddle***](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/35054)

And your update statement can be:

```
UPDATE hd_posts
SET post_content = 
       replace(
        replace( @pc:=post_content, substring( @pc, 1, INSTR( @pc, ']' ) ), 
                 '<img src="http://mydomain.com/my-theme/images/'
        ), '[/attachment]', '" />' )
```

Comment: Wow, you rock! That was a lot more complicated than I was expecting. I can't thank you enough for your expertise. Works perfectly.